# Codeigniter cannot access controller without index.php

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

My local xampp codeigniter projec's url was 
http://localhost/ci_yudeesh/index.php
But then wanted to remove the **index.php** part from the url so I followed the steps given in the userguide.

After that i could access the project without **index.php** with the url
http://localhost/ci_yudeesh/

I have a controller named **Home** and I can access this using http://localhost/ci_yudeesh/index.php/home
, but when try to access this using http://localhost/ci_yudeesh/home it gives this error:

[image: error image]

this is my config:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/ci_yudeesh/';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

this is my .htaccess:

```
<IfModule authz_core_module>
    Require all denied
</IfModule>
<IfModule !authz_core_module>
    Deny from all
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

this is my route:

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'Home';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

Can someone help me fixing this? I tried all the other answers to similar type questions but none worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the .htaccess from the **application** folder and put it outside the application folder and written only the below code in it. If it not work then I will give you another .htaccess code.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the .htaccess file . Remove the codes from the existing file and add the following codes on the file :-

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond $1 !^(index.php|resources|robots.txt)

RewriteBase /ci_yudeesh/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]